# How to listen to selection changes on TableViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp, selectionchanged

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP application and I'm trying to update an expression value which is provided by `MySourceProvider` according to selection changes on a `TableViewer` in `MyEditorPart`.

`MyEditorPart` instance defines a `TableViewer` like this:

```
public class MyEditorPart extends EditorPart {  

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {  

  TableViewer tableviewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.CHECK);
  tableviewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
  getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableViewer);  

...
```

`MySourceProvider` have some expression values like this:

```
public class MySourceProvider extends AbstractSourceProvider {

public static final String EXPR = "org.xyz.isEntrySelected";
// other expressions

@Override
public String[] getProvidedSourceNames() {
  return new String[] { EXPR,
  // other expressions
  };
}

@Override
public Map getCurrentState() {
  HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
  map.put(EXPR, expr_value); // expr_value calculated by the listener
  // other expressions
  return map;
}
```

I want to change `expr_value` according to selection changes on `TableViewer`.
I registered the listener like this:

```
window.getSelectionService().addPostSelectionListener(MyEditorPartId, selectionListener);  
private final ISelectionListener selectionListener = new  SelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        handleEvent();
    }
};
```

The listener registers successfully but gets notified only once if I clicked somewhere on `MyEditorPart` (not just `TableViewer` but the whole editor). To get notified again, I have to click on some other view (or editor) part to lose focus and then click again on `MyEditorPart`.

**1.** Why does the listener gets notified only once when `MyEditorPart` re-gains focus?
**2.** How to listen **only** to selection changes to `TableViewer` rows?

What am I missing here? What is the proper way to listen to selection changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is not a SelectionListener, but a [SelectionChangedListener](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html#jfacetable_selectionlistener).

With this you can write the following code:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    IStructuredSelection selection = viewer.getStructuredSelection();
    Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
    // do something with it
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand but I have to create the listener on another class `MySourceProvider`, that is why I'm trying to use `getSelectionService().addPostSelectionListener()` and this method only accepts `ISelectionListener`? Instead of this, should I use your solution with an EventBroker to notify `MySourceProvider`?

Comment: What you need is likely a simple callback function. Try to avoid overcomplicating things with JFace tricks. If the action you want to respond to is "user selecting an item in a table", then the JFace listener you need is selectionChangedListener. From that on, the rest is just sharing references and calling methods you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that this form of `addPostSelectionListener` only fires when the part becomes active. Use the:

```
addPostSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener)
```

form of the listener which is called for every selection change.

You can then test the `IWorkbenchPart` id in the listener:

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(final IWorkbenchPart part, final ISelection selection)
{
  if (MyEditorPartId.equals(part.getSite().getId()))
   {
     // your code
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately it has the same problem, it only fires once. Forgive my silly question but examples I found, always use this listener - selectionprovider mechanism from a `ViewPart`, I wonder if it has something to do with using a `EditorPart`? Because I've some `ViewPart` classes that uses this mechanism and they just work fine.